# TrialArchivingService is this a new process or is it malware?

Tags: macos, software-update, monterey, malware

Found this new process TrialArchivingService that was using a lot of cpu. It was started by user. Has anyone else seen this process. All input is welcome.
OS - Monterey 12.3
Thanks,
M

Comment: https://eclecticlight.co/2022/03/31/what-is-triald-and-why-is-it-taking-so-much-disk-space/ an Apple default process, and apparently an ongoing mystery about what it actually does

Answer (score 0):

`TrialArchivingService` (or `triald`) have definitely been seen by other users, and most likely are not malware. In fact, `triald` is running on my computer right now.

It's not exactly obvious what the process does, but it most likely has to do with Siri (based on what I found at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253760894?page=2). If you have Siri enabled, try turning it off for a couple of days and see if that fixes the issue. Likewise, if you have Siri *off*, try turning it on for a couple of days and see if *that* fixes the issue. After changing your Siri settings, you can delete your Siri history via system preferences (System Preferences > Siri > Delete Siri & Dictation History) to make `TrialArchivingService` take up less CPU.

If disk space is becoming a problem, or turning Siri on/off doesn't help reduce `TrialArchivingService`/`triald`'s activity, try these steps from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253760894?page=2 (edited for clarity):

1. Boot into Safe Mode. Run Activity Monitor and kill any processes that contain the word "trial."
2. Immediately open Finder. Navigate to the  `~/Library/` folder by using `Shift-Command-G` and typing in `~/Library/`. Move the "trial" folder to the trash, and empty the trash.
3. Reboot normally (out of Safe Mode), and the trial folder in ~/Library/ will be re-created, taking up much less disk space.

Regardless of what exactly this process is for, it is a legitimate pre-installed Apple program and isn't malware, so no need to worry there! I hope this solution helps you solve your problem!